# InfoWindows on Markers in StreetView

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

According to the Google documentation, when you create a marker on a gmap the marker is also 'copied' onto the StreetView version of the map.

However, onClick event binding are not copied (or at least don't appear to be), so I can't open the InfoWindow on the marker when in StreetView.

Ideally I'd actually be able to define different content for the StreetView version of the InfoWindow, but right now I can't even get the same InfoWindow to open.

I'm using code from the Google examples to create the InfoWindow binding on the main map markers as follows (wrapped in a function):

```
google.maps.event.clearListeners(marker,'click');
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
//      infoWindow.open(map.getStreetView(), marker);
});
```

That commented line was my attempt to add the opener for the StreetView version of the marker, but it doesn't do anything.

Note: `map` is the map object, `marker` is the marker object and `html` contains the HTML string to be put into the InfoWindow. All of this works for the main map marker so it's mot a problem of null variables being passed or anything. The problem is only with getting the StreetView marker to pop it's InfoWindow when clicked.

---

Note that this is not a duplicate of [Google Maps StreetView InfowIndows opening on map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37778271/google-maps-streetview-infowindows-opening-on-map) as this issue was due to a coding issue on my side and was solved using the steps in the accepted answer. The linked question refers to a change Google made to their API which broke some of this functionality or at least caused it to behave in an undesirable way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [InfoWindows on Markers in StreetView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686194/adding-infowindow-to-custom-google-streetview)

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll take a look. Every search I did returned results for putting Street View /into/ InfoWindows!

Comment: OK, the problem seems to be when I have both Info Windows trying to open when clicked... I wonder if the second .open() is closing the one on the map before it is seen, then opening Street View closes the just opened window there...

Comment: Looks like you only have one infowindow.  you can't have the same infowindow on both at the same time.

Comment: That's the clue I needed! The market gets copied into the Street View, but not any associated Info Window. That makes perfect sense - just got to fix it now. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps StreetView InfowIndows opening on map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37778271/google-maps-streetview-infowindows-opening-on-map)

Comment: I've added answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37778271/google-maps-streetview-infowindows-opening-on-map/56808739#56808739

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first error was that I was trying to display the same InfoWindow on both the map copy and the StreetView copy of the marker.

This is not allowed, and so creating a second instance of the InfoWindow fixed that problem.

In order to create two separate InfoWindows and attach them to the two copies of the same marker I had to modify my code somewhat.

The code above was from a function called `bindInfoWindow()` based on the code in the Google documentation. I modified this to include a parameter to specify either the `map` or the `streetView` object.

The next problem was that the `clearListeners` method was being called every time `bindInfoWindow()` was being called, effectively removing the `onClick` binding for the map copy of the marker.

I therefore moved the `clearListeners` call to outside of the function and call it before calling binInfoWindow().

The final function looks like below:

```
function bindInfoWindow(marker, mapOrStreetViewObject, infoWindowObject, html) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindowObject.setContent(html);
        infoWindowObject.open(mapOrStreetViewObject, marker);
    });
}
```

This is then called with the sequence:

```
// Note that the mapObject and streetViewObject variables are defined elsewheer to point to the map nd streetView instances in use.

//Define the local variables that we'll use in the calls
var myMapInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
var mapInfoWindowHTML = 'some stuff';
var myStreetViewInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
var streetViewInfoWindowHTML = 'some stuff';

// Remove any existing listeners from the marker
google.maps.event.clearListeners(marker,'click');

// Bind the event for the map marker click
bindInfoWindow(markerObject, mapObject, myMapInfoWindow, mapInfoWindowHTML);
//Bind the event for the StreetView marker click
bindInfoWindow(markerObject, streetViewObjectObject, myStreetViewInfoWindow, streetViewInfoWindowHTML);
```

What is nice about this is that if you open an InfoWindow on the map, then open StreetView the same InfoWindow is already open on the Street View!

Comment: In the last couple of weeks, this solution has stopped working. See my post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37778271/google-maps-streetview-infowindows-opening-on-map for more info...

Answer (score 4):

## TL;DR

I was able to make it work with the following steps:

1. Have two (2) independent InfoWindows; one for the map, and one for the street view panorama
2. Explicitly define the value for [`InfoWindowOptions.position`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/info-window#InfoWindowOptions.position)  when instantiating the InfoWindows
3. Pass `null` as the argument to the `anchor` parameter of the [`InfoWindow.open()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/info-window#InfoWindow.open) method

#### Example

```
// The geolocation point
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(10.5884708621,122.7016563883);

// The map
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: point,
    zoom: 20,
    mapTypeId: "satellite",
});

// The marker
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    title: "Hello world!",
    position: point,
    label: {text:"hello",color:"#ffffffde",fontWeight:"bold",fontSize:"18px"},
    map: map
});

// The InfoWindow for the map view
var mapInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "foo",
    position: point // refer to step #2
});

// The InfoWindow for the street view
var streetViewPanoramaInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "bar",
    position: point, // refer to step #2
    disableAutoPan: true // optional but helpful
});

// The click event handler for the marker
marker.addListener('click', function() {
    var streetViewPanorama = map.getStreetView();

    // when streetview was engaged
    if(streetViewPanorama.getVisible()==true) {
        streetViewPanoramaInfoWindow.open(streetViewPanorama); // refer to step #3
    }
    // when normal aerial view was engaged
    else {
        mapInfoWindow.open(map); // refer to step #3
    }
});
```